# Symfony2 - Validation.yml with Class and Extended Class

Tags: oop, validation, symfony

I've got an 'addressClass' and a 'shippingAddressClass'. 'ShippingAdress' extends 'Address' and they both validate identically EXCEPT 'shippingAddress' invalidates when a PO Box is detected. While a PO box is a perfectly valid billing address, UPS doesn't ship to them.

#### Hypothetically, What's the SF2 Best Practice for validating `Bird` which `extends` `Animal`?

Should we duplicate the .yml which we used to validate `Animal`? Essentially giving us two fairly identical sections (see below). In this case, the `getters` are a little different from `Animal` to `Bird` but the `properties` require pretty identical validation rules.

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Animal:
        properties:
            name:
                - NotBlank: ~
        getters:
            isAnimal:
                - "True"


Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Bird:
        properties:
            name:
                - NotBlank: ~
        getters:
            isAnimal:
                - "True"
            isBird
                - "True"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Validator Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) is smart and validates against the constraints of the origin classes. So in my `Animal`,`Bird` example, we would only need:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Animal:
        properties:
            name:
                - NotBlank: ~
        getters:
            isAnimal:
                - "True"


Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Bird:
        getters:
            isBird
                - "True"
```